# Microcontroller MOSFET-driven RGB LED strip controller

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, led, led-strip

I'm trying to DIY a very simple RGB strip controller, nothing fancy.

The goal is that it has to be driven from a 3.3 V / 5 V microcontroller output, using some N-channel MOSFETs. I will control them with PWM at maybe 200 Hz.

Since I've never worked with these practically, please take a look at this schematic and tell me if I missed something.

From what I found online this should do the job just fine, I just want to be sure before ordering a PCB.

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 2):

First off, your gate pull-down resistors can be increased from 10K to 100K.

Your gate pull-down resistors there to turn off the MOSFETs when (a) the MCU board is unplugged or (b) its driving I/O pins are high-impedance inputs after reset, before software has set them to outputs.

For (a), there is no current through the pull-downs.

For (b), there is the leakage from a logic driver. You can look that up in the MCU datasheet but it's typically <10 uA. Your 100K would develop <0.1 V across it, which is plenty low enough to disable the MOSFETs.

Secondly, I would add a 100K resistor across each MOSFET's drain and source. This is a simple and cheap static protection to make handling the board easier. It should have practically no effect on your MOSFET loads. You will already have 100K resistors so this is a simpler parts list than TVS diodes or other solutions. I have used it on many such designs with great success.

Thirdly, you don't specify a switching speed so I can't comment on the 220R resistors. Its good that you have series resistors. When driving a MOSFET gate from a logic gate, a series resistor should always be used as the MOSFET presents a capacitance to the logic gate. The resistor limits the charging/discharging current into the gate capacitance. This sometimes gets forgotten.

If it's simple on/off switching, the resistor can be 1K, to limit the max. instantaneous current to 3.3-odd mA. For PWM switching frequencies, an actual resistor value can be calculated from the gate Io(max). After that, the resistor and the MOSFET gate capacitance will lead to a max. rise/fall time which gives the switching times. In PWM, losses occur during switching time, which can be weighed up as a percentage of the PWM cycle period.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see why you would use 100k over 10k. And I put the resistor there because the mcu i intend to use has all its I/O as input by default, also to keep the mosfet off until the mcu's firmware has been loaded (has something to do with the capacitances i heard). Also gonna put the extra 100k over S and D.

Comment: To add to the switching speed, I'm not sure of that yet, but it shouldn't be more than 500Hz. I'll look into it further tomorrow and decide if a slightly higher gate resistor value would be better.

Comment: If anything, you’d want a lower value gate resistor. 22 Ohm would be closer to what is required.

Comment: I would also add place holders for snubbers across the outputs. Can't tell how long the led strip is.

Comment: @Kartman, I've detailed why not. Can you give reasons for a lower/22R series that contests what I've written or why you'd want 22R on a logic output.

Comment: @Mike isn't a snubber network more needed for inductive loads? Or with loads that have a big inrush current? I'm not going to use massively long led strips so it should be fine?

Comment: It should probably be fine, but if you got space on the board just place the footprints, populate them only if you run into issues.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! A small RC network across the mosfets D-S should do i suppose? I got plenty of space for some smd components.

Comment: @TonyM I just did some calculations, and I think i'm going to stick with a 220 ohm resistor, the µC can source up to 25mA max on each I/O pin (80mA on all), with this resistor it should be around 15mA. The gate charge time is then around 1.53ns. Which is not terrible.

Comment: @ian, you don't state switching freq (please edit into your question) but 1.53 ns is OTT fast, right for 10 MHz switching. To get it, you spike 15 mA needlessly from the rail then discharge it to GND half a switching cycle later. Three simultaneously need 45 mA. That's bad design. Reduce the load on your logic I/O, it's pointlessly high. Use 1K, spike 3.3 mA and switch the gate in 8 ns. That's hardly excruciatingly slow. That'll do 2 MHz cleanly and you're, what 200 Hz tops for PWM? Cables won't give more than about 5 kHz, if there was any point in more. LEDs are averagers, you won't see diff.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks for the correction! I didn't add a switching frequency since i haven't set one yet, but i will probably go for 200Hz as you mentioned. Since as you said, led's don't need such high switching frequency, I'll change the gate resistors to 1k. There's indeed no need to froce more current out of the µC.